# How do we promote our site?

Tags: discussion, new-users, 7-questions

After half of the official 3 month beta phase, let's recap some numbers:

[image: area 51]

- With **11.9** questions per day, we have an *excellent* influx of new curious content.
- Also, **90%** answered questions is *excellent* and indicates a healthy beta.
- The **929** visits per day is *okay* and increasing steady and I'm quite certain we will reach levels of several thousend hits per day very soon, as ethereum is quite a hot topic on the web (some days ago it was at around 600ish).
- The **1.5** answer ration is *okay*, but shows we could use more expertise on the site, e.g. more experienced users contributing high quality answers.

All that looks, as I said, *okay*. **But the real issue I see is the lack of a solid user base** and a very slow growth of the user base. For graduation we would require at least 5 users with at least 10k (access moderator tools) reputation and a solid group of active users with at least 3k (cast close votes) reputation. How can we achieve this?

How to gain more users and more quality answers at the same time? How to generate more overall site expertise?

I would like to have one idea per answer and everyone can use up-/downvote the proposals.

Answer (score 11):

My first idea would be a closer service integration on [/r/ethereum](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/) subreddit. There is a user base of around 10k subscribers and 100 average users online.

#### Proposal

It could be designed like follows:

1. Coordinate with subreddit moderators whether such an integration would be welcome on /r/ethereum.
2. Setup some RSS-Reddit-Feed-Bot which automatically crossposts links from new questions on this Stackexchange on the subreddit. (Currently around 12 per day.)
3. Introduce mechanics on the subreddit to recommend new redditors to ask questions on Stackexchange rather than on reddit.

Please, up- or downvote if you like an reddit integration. Comments welcome.

#### Status

To be discussed with the /r/ethereum team.

Comment: As a subreddit mod, I am for more integration between the sub and stack exchange. However, idk if that means an auto-reddit post bot or not. At minimum the sub should make more efforts to point people to the stack exchange, maybe by making it more relevant in the side bar or in the text the user is presented with when they add a link/question.

Comment: Could we make it automatically post questions that get more than a certain amount of points?

Comment: @MrChico good idea.

Comment: Not familiar with bots, but one idea is to have a bot that looks for common questions on reddit that have solid answers here and auto-post the links to this SE?  Examples of such questions are: what is Ethereum, where to buy, what is gas...

Comment: Content/Links should come from Stackexchange and go automatically to Reddit. Visitors and users should come from Reddit and create high quality content on Stackexchange. Not the other way around (this is important). We dont need Stackexchange if we just have bots here asking questions.

Answer (score 4):

Another idea would be a twitter integration into the [#ethereum](https://twitter.com/hashtag/ethereum) hashtag. It's the main tag for ethereum and contains around 15 tweets per hour.

#### Proposal

1. We could setup an RSS-Twitter-Feed-Bot which automatically crossposts links from new questions on Twitter.
2. These tweets would include the question, the #ethereum tag and maybe other tags of the question like #smart-contracts or #scalability.

Please, up- or downvote if you like an twitter integration. Comments welcome.

#### Status

Currently testing the bot: https://twitter.com/ethoverflow

Comment: There is already a Twitter bot out there doing the same thing: Ethereum SE (@StackEthereum): https://twitter.com/StackEthereum